# How to fetch all values after a particular date for a column in same table using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, aggregate

have a db table with values

table : exam

```
name     department      result       date
mark      cse             pass       2019-03-04 10:20:11.000    
leo       cse             pass       2019-03-05 10:20:11.000
stan      cse             fail       2019-03-06 10:20:11.000
mark      cse             fail       2019-03-07 10:20:11.000    
leo       cse             pass       2019-03-08 10:20:11.000
stan      cse             fail       2019-03-09 10:20:11.000
mark      cse             pass       2019-03-10 10:20:11.000    
leo       cse             pass       2019-03-11 10:20:11.000
stan      cse             pass       2019-03-12 10:20:11.000
mark      cse             pass       2019-05-12 10:20:11.000
```

using sql query users values after his last fail date   , if pass is not there for user ignore his data

```
mark      cse             pass       2019-03-10 10:20:11.000
mark      cse             pass       2019-05-12 10:20:11.000
stan      cse             pass       2019-03-12 10:20:11.000
```

tried this

```
select exam.*
from exam
where exam.date > (select max(exam.date)
                from exam
                where exam.name = exam.name and exam.result = 'fail'
               );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mySQL correlated Subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163462/mysql-correlated-subquery)

Comment: @Isaac this is from same table . PL check

Comment: Yes, but you are referencing it twice which is as if it was two tables.

Comment: i'm new to sql trying to figure out how to do that

Comment: Ok, maybe the correlated subquery is not the way to go. As you will learn there are many different approaches. You have to go with what makes sense for your situation and that you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM exam e1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT name, max(date) MaxDate
  FROM exam 
  WHERE result = 'fail'
  GROUP BY name
) e2 on e1.name = e2.name and e1.date > e2.MaxDate
ORDER BY name
```

Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=25d8d3889c79a3a1d245db9209a9bae7).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from exam tab1
where tab1.exam_date > (select max(tab2.exam_date)
                from exam tab2
                where tab1.name = tab2.name and tab2.result = 'fail'
               );
```

Your SQL is correct but you need to provide an alias for table names in correlated subquery.

Demo : https://rextester.com/VKLZ36983